# How to count point shp inside polygon shp using Python?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, polygon, point, python-2.7

This is my first time here, so I'll try to be as specific as I can.

What I'm trying to do is found out which polygon contains the most points and write the result in a text file.

Here is my script : (tab25Select are the polygons and chefLyr are the points)

```
chefLyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(cheflieuIN, "chefLyr")

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tab25Select, ["Numero", "Name"]) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        chefTab25Max = 0
        chefTab25 = arcpy.GetCount_management(arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(chefLyr, "WITHIN", tab25Select))
        arcpy.AddMessage(cheflTab25)
        for chf in cheflTab25:
            if chf > chefTab25Max:
                chefTab25Max = cheflTab25
                a = row[0]
                b = row[1]

ficTxt.write("\r\n The polygon containing the most point is :{0}".format(chefTab25Max))



ficTxt.close()
```

If anyone can help :)

Comment: I am sure you can script something like this...http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30779

Comment: Every time the "for row in rows" loop is run, the counter will be set to 0, and from what I understand, you want to get the max out of your entire loop, so you may want to initialize it outside. Also, arcpy.addMessage takes in a string, so if you could clarify from where "cheflTab25" comes from, that would be great.

Comment: This seems like an elaborate way to rewrite the Spatial Join tool, which counts points within polygons (Join_Count field).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can crush this down to 3 lines of code, no cursors required!

```py
import arcpy
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis("Site", "points","in_memory/points_SpatialJoin", "JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY", "KEEP_ALL", "", "INTERSECT")
arcpy.Statistics_analysis("points_SpatialJoin", "in_memory/stats", "Join_Count SUM","Id")
```

Then simply sort the table to find the polygon with most points.

Comment: I've never been able to find a satisfactory answer for a system tool for saving out as a CSV file. So I tend to work with geodatabase tables/dbase. If a text file is required I would probably do it your way. Sort the table then read the first row and at that point use a cursor. But for this task I would almost certainly have approached it using modelbuilder writing to dBase file. Horses for courses! :)

Answer (score 8):

The following approach uses a [Search Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000) and [Python dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to perform the following workflow:

1. Select points within each polygon feature
2. Update dictionary with key (OID) and value (point count) for each iteration
3. Find max point value and corresponding OID and write to a text file

---

```
import arcpy, os

points = r'C:\temp\mytest\points.shp'
polys = r'C:\temp\mytest\polys.shp'

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(points, "pointsLyr")

data = {}

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polys, ["OID@", "SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("pointsLyr", select_features = row[1])
        count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("pointsLyr").getOutput(0))
        data[row[0]] = count

# Write the output to a text file
text_file = open(r"C:\temp\Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write("OID = %s; count = %s" % (max(data, key = data.get), data[max(data, key = data.get)]))
text_file.close()
```

---

[image]

[image]